# Binding a Non-Zero Texture Crashes Program With VBO's

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, vbo

So I wanted to implement a simple VBO to see if it was worth switching from display lists for static objects in my scene. So far, I don't think Im doing it anytime soon. So heres my problem: I can render vertices fine, but as soon as I throw in texture coordinates, it crashes. So I do a bit of experimenting and its because I'm binding a texture to the thing. I have NEVER heard of this as being a problem. Literally the exact same code, using display lists works. Here is my code:

```
//create a vertex buffer object for the particles to use
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

        //create the data, this is really sloppy
        float QuadVertextData[] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0};
        float QuadTextureData[] = {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0};

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*3, &QuadVertextData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        //generate another buffer for the texcoords
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBOT);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOT);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*2, &QuadTextureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

and rendering:

```
        glUseProgram(shader);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOT);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

I really have no idea why this is happening, Doing a texture without a shader crashes it, binding a shader without a texture crashes it. Any help or advice?

Comment: Can you compile your program in debug mode, run it in a debugger, and get a backtrace from the crash?

Comment: You should be able to see exactly what line it is crashing on.

Answer (score -1):

In a core opengl profile, you need to use VAOs in order to work with calls such as glDrawArrays and glDrawElements. A VAO (vertex array object) is a list of binding points for VBOs that encapsulates information such as data format and number of components for each VBO that is bound to it. In code it looks something like this.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*3, &QuadVertextData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbot);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbot);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*2, &QuadTextureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The 0 and 1 (the first argument to glVertexAttribPointer) specifies the generic vertex attribute index in your shader. The 2 and 3 (the second argument) specify the number of components. Your input should be defined like this in the shader in order to work with this VAO:

```
layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
layout(location=1) in vec2 textureCoordinates;
```

Before drawing anything, you just have to use the shader program, bind your texture and bind the VAO:

```
glUseProgram(shader);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

Don't forget to set the texture location of the sampler2D uniform in the shader.

If you want to learn more about switching to the OpenGL core profile, I recommand the tutorials from http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

Comment: Why is it that in tutorials I've seen with people using VBO's they don't have to modify the shaders to use layouts and the like?

Comment: This assumes that the OP wants to use the core profile, which is never stated anywhere in the question. Additionally, not using VAOs shouldn't be causing a crash.

Comment: While this is mostly true (`GL_QUADS` does not exist in the core profile), I don't see how it's related to the question. The OP is obviously not using the core profile.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo So, I should be disregarding this answer, as it isn't valid?

Comment: @BlueSpud Mostly. While IMO it's worth learning the core profile for the flexibility it gives you, this answer doesn't actually address the problem you are having, and is unlikely to solve it.